# Crashing on move_uploaded_file command

Tags: php, file

I'm getting a 500 error when executing the command `move_uploaded_file`. (Note that I am not returning `false`). Not sure how to get any error messages from this, but that would obviously help!

I start with an array `$_FILES` that in my test contains metadata on two files (it's a very controlled test). This line used to work just fine when I was only uploading a single file, so I know that it is not a server permissions issue.

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES);
$target_dir = "client_resources/";

foreach ($_FILES as $thisFile) {

    print_r($thisFile);

    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($thisFile['name']);

    echo $thisFile['tmp_name'];
    echo $target_file;

    if (move_uploaded_file($thisFile['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        echo 'uploaded';
    } else {
        // don't know how to get the error message from here
    }
}
?>
```

If I comment out the `move_uploaded_file` block, I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [file0] => Array
        (
            [name] => back.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php8030.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3936
        )

    [file1] => Array
        (
            [name] => images.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php8041.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 8257
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => back.jpeg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php8030.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 3936
)
C:\Windows\Temp\php8030.tmp
client_resources/back.jpeg
Array
(
    [name] => images.jpeg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php8041.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 8257
)
C:\Windows\Temp\php8041.tmp
client_resources/images.jpeg
```

I've also tried to put this line in a `try-catch` block, but I still crash.

Can anyone see why this won't work any longer? Thanks!

Comment: in your codes you have not checked file upload size!, default file upload size is 2MB have you checked your php.ini?

Comment: In my actual, full-blown code, I do check the size. As I mentioned, this command used to work when my script was just uploading a single file. Also, you can see in the output what the file sizes are.

Comment: i think you are trying to upload multiple images . right???

Comment: Turn on error reporting - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and show us the errors please. I'll also warrant a guess at the reason it's failing is because you aren't using an absolute file path (`$target_file`).

Comment: @Darren - that was it. I changed the $target_dir line to `$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/client_resources/';` and it worked. If you propose that as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Randall Done and dusted :). I know the feeling with little issues like this, day long head scratches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always turn on error reporting when creating a script to ensure you won't run into any issues. That can be done with:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now the other issue you're facing is that you're trying to store the file in a relative path. To move files, you need an absolute path. You could do as you've done with:

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/client_resources/';
```

Or alternatively look into [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd). (<sup>*Gets the current working directory of your site*</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

use this  to get the error

```
$_FILES["pictures"]["error"];
```

if you are using multiple file uploading then use upload function like array like this .

```
   //Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    }
  }
}
```

here is the description for errors [Errors in file uploading](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: I don't see how this will work since my program crashes before I have a chance to output the error message.

Comment: The debug output already shows that there was not error with the uploading part itself.

Answer (score -2):

try like this,

```
$move = @ move_uploaded_file($thisFile['tmp_name'], $target_file);  
if(!$move)
    echo 'Not uploaded';
else
 echo 'uploaded';
```

Comment: Thank you. That stops it from crashing. My output now includes 'Not Uploaded' (no surprise there :P !)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess is that it is because your solution only delays the problem from being noticed. I already know that the upload is failing. That is why I can't accept this as the solution - it doesn't really solve anything.

Comment: my answer,answered your question or not ? your problem is crashing right, then what else you want  me to do, write code for you?? i only answered for your question "Crashing on move_uploaded_file command" that's all after applying my answer you didn't got crashed right?

Comment: whoever put down vote please put reason for that else get out of this place

Comment: I didn't down vote but this is a bad answer. Don't **EVER** suppress a function error with `@`. Fix the error instead.